# Quickbooks Consolibyte PHP issue, says XML is incorrect

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml, qbwc

I'm trying to use this system to sync my database from postgresql to quickbooks web connector https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php, but it's giving me all sorts of XML issues.
Here is my QWC file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<QBWCXML>
    <AppName>QuickBooks PostgreSQL Mirror</AppName>
    <AppID></AppID>
    <AppURL>https://myserver.com/admin/qbwc/pgsql_server.php</AppURL>
    <AppDescription>QuickBooks PostgreSQL Mirror</AppDescription>
    <AppSupport>https://myserver.com/admin/qbwc/pgsql_server.php?support=1</AppSupport>
    <UserName>quickbooks</UserName>
    <OwnerID>{fb0c8866-7719-e4a4-e9bb-c81c30cd1045}</OwnerID>
    <FileID>{788e593c-0b38-4824-3d7d-5b9a793316df}</FileID>
    <QBType>QBFS</QBType>
    <Notify>true</Notify>
    <Scheduler>
        <RunEveryNMinutes>1</RunEveryNMinutes>
    </Scheduler>
    <IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
</QBWCXML>
```

Here is my PHP connector app, copied from the example file for PostgreSQL syncing, but modified with my info:

```php
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);

require_once '../libraries/vendor/consolibyte/quickbooks/QuickBooks.php';

if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_set'))
{
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Detroit');
}

$username = 'quickbooks';
$password = 'password';

$dsn = 'pgsql://postgres:password@localhost/quickbooks';

if (!QuickBooks_Utilities::initialized($dsn))
{
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    
    set_time_limit(0);
    
    $driver_options = array(
        );
        
    $init_options = array(
        'quickbooks_sql_enabled' => true, 
        );
        
    QuickBooks_Utilities::initialize($dsn, $driver_options, $init_options);
    QuickBooks_Utilities::createUser($dsn, $username, $password);
    
    exit;
}

$mode = QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server_SQL::MODE_READWRITE;

$conflicts = QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server_SQL::CONFLICT_LOG;

$delete = QUICKBOOKS_SERVER_SQL_DELETE_FLAG;

$hooks = array();

$soap_options = array();

$handler_options = array(
    'deny_concurrent_logins' => false, 
    'deny_reallyfast_logins' => false,
);

$driver_options = array();

$sql_options = array(
    'only_import' => array( 
        QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_CUSTOMER, 
    ),
    'only_add' => array( 
        QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_CUSTOMER, 
    ),
    'only_modify' => array( 
        QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_CUSTOMER, 
    ), 
);

$callback_options = array();

$Server = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server_SQL(
    $dsn, 
    '1 minute', 
    $mode, 
    $conflicts, 
    $delete,
    $username, 
    array(), 
    array(), 
    $hooks, 
    QUICKBOOKS_LOG_DEVELOP, 
    QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_BUILTIN, 
    QUICKBOOKS_WSDL,
    $soap_options, 
    $handler_options, 
    $driver_options,
    $sql_options, 
    $callback_options);

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
ob_start();
$Server->handle(true, true);
print(ob_get_clean());

exit;
```

I know it runs and connects to my DB, since I have all the `qb_` tables added, but no data is syncing back and forth. I also get this error whenever I run it:

[image]

Here are my logs:

```
20210526.15:53:01 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : updateWS() for application = 'QuickBooks PostgreSQL Mirror - myserver.com' has STARTED
20210526.15:53:01 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.getUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock = FALSE
20210526.15:53:01 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to True
20210526.15:53:01 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session locked *********************
20210526.15:53:01 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : Initiated connection to the following application.
20210526.15:53:01 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppName: QuickBooks PostgreSQL Mirror - myserver.com
20210526.15:53:01 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppUniqueName (if available): QuickBooks PostgreSQL Mirror - myserver.com
20210526.15:53:01 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppURL: https://myserver.com/admin/qbwc/pgsql_server.php
20210526.15:53:01 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : *** Calling serverVersion().
20210526.15:53:02 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : Received from serverVersion() following parameter:<serverVersionRet="PHP QuickBooks SOAP Server v3.0 at /admin/qbwc/pgsql_server.php">
20210526.15:53:02 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : *** Calling clientVersion() with following parameter:<productVersion="2.3.0.198">
20210526.15:53:02 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : Received from clientVersion() following parameter:<clientVersionRet="">
20210526.15:53:02 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : This application agrees with the current version of QBWebConnector. Allowing update operation.
20210526.15:53:02 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Authenticating to application 'QuickBooks PostgreSQL Mirror - myserver.com', username = 'quickbooks'
20210526.15:53:02 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : *** Calling authenticate() with following parameters:<userName="quickbooks"><password=<MaskedForSecurity>
20210526.15:53:02 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message.
Client found response content type of 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with an empty response.
More info:
StackTrace =    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebServiceDoc.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebService.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.authenticate(String UserName, String Password)
   at QBWebConnector.WebService.do_authenticate(String& ticket, String& companyFileName)
Source = System.Web.Services
20210526.15:53:02 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
20210526.15:53:02 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20210526.15:53:02 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : Update completed with errors. See log (QWClog.txt) for details.
```

Comment: Are those logs from the PHP instance or a separate process? They seem like .NET logs. Either way they seem to indicate that the diffusion authentication SOAP request has the (slightly) wrong content-type.

Comment: Error log are from quickbooks logs in Windows, so probably .net. The API connecting to it is in PHP, but I've triple checked, PHP is sending the correct headers.

Comment: It'll be worth going over the PHP logs on the server too, it's possible that an error is occurring and an error page is being returned instead of the XML content.